# How to set thumbnail image for a (child) theme

Tags: themes, child-theme, thumbnails

I've created a basic child image for [twentytwelve](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/twentytwelve), and it works as expected. The only issue is that it does not have a thumbnail image in the themes page:

[image]

How do I set a thumbnail image for my child theme?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Create image file in PNG Format having name screenshot.png and save it in themes root folder.The recommended image size is 880x660. Even recommended image size is 880x660 though it will only be shown as 387x290 but the double-sized image allows for high-resolution viewing on HiDPI displays.

For more information see [this page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Screenshot).

If you don’t already have a screenshot of your theme, You can create one easily by following below steps:

1. Point your browser to the blog currently using the theme.
2. Press the Print Screen button on the keyboard.
3. Open a new file in Photoshop.
4. Change the size to 300 by 225 (in pixels)
5. Press Ctrl + v or Right click > Paste.
6. With the Move tool activated, resize the screenshot to in the 600 x
   450 space.
7. Go to File > Save for Web…
8. Save it as a PNG file.
9. Name it screenshot such as screenshot.png
10. Place your image file in the theme’s folder.

Comment: Update: "The recommended image size is 880x660. The screenshot will only be shown as 387x290, but the over double-sized image allows for high-resolution viewing on HiDPI displays."

Comment: Just wanted to clarify on Vinod's answer regarding #10 that you must place the "screenshot" file in the same location as the `style.css` otherwise the "screenshot" will not show. [Here's a good read on what else could deter the "Screenshot' from showing](https://medium.com/@micsumner/the-correct-wordpress-theme-screenshot-size-name-and-format-fae988e3215b).

Answer (score 4):

What Vinod Dalvi said, except:

Make sure the file is named using *all lower case*:

- *`screenshot.png`*

or

- *`screenshot.jpg`*.

*`screenshot.PNG`* won't work!